# Laravel 5.6 share auth id issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to pass user id in the `boot` function of the `AppServiceProvider` class (as it written [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)) but for some reason `Auth::user()` object is empty.

**myAppName/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        URL::forceScheme('https');
        View::share('user_info', Auth::user());
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And then in in some blade template:

`<p>{{ $user_info->id }}</p>`

As a result an error occurs:

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

There is same error if want to pass `Auth::user()->id`

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel blade has access to the currently authenticated user, you don't have to explicitly use view::share for that.

You can simply access auth user in the blade as :

`{{ Auth::user()->id }}`

You might check if user already authenticated via `@guest` helper or auth check method:

```
@if (Auth::check())
  // authenticated
  {{ Auth::user()->id }}
@else
  // Not authenticaed
@endif
```

Comment: Also, there is no `auth()->user()` at `ServiceProvider` layer. See laravel lifecycle: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/lifecycle

Comment: Thanks! Ok but what if I want to get some data from i.e. `user_gruops` table which is related to the `users` table by `id`? I think it would be convenient to set all user info data in one place and assign specific variable and then use it in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

for security reason Laravel ServiceProvider doesn't have any access to session. And After login laravel maintain current login user into Session. That's why you are getting this error.

For your problem you can share variable into Controller(App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php)  class's constructor.

Something like this:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('user',auth()->user());
    }
}
```

All controllers in Laravel default extends this class. Then you just have to execute constructor of parent class like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

One more thing default session is not sharable into Constructor also. You have to enable it by adding this two lines into App/Http/Kernel.php class's $middleware array.

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
       //
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
       //
    ];
}
```

Make sure you are removing this two lines from $middlewareGroups array. Good luck !!!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For security reasons there is no explanation in the docs how to share auth data (just kidding). Actually, this is not a solution because it requires execution constructor of parent class in every controller where this shared variable is used. Looks like another one crutch. After some searching I understood that this issue is kind of pain in Laravel. It's a pity. I started to looking for some other framework now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution, just need to add View Composer to the `AppServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.navbar', function($view) {

           $view->with('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then just put a variable in the `navbar` template like this:
`<p>{{ $user_id }}</p>`

Explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3mKQ0o1Xr4)